# Как в одном запросе через AJAX залить на сервер фото и текст?

Tags: php, javascript

Как в одном запросе через AJAX залить на сервер фото и текст? 
Фото может быть много

Comment: а юзать jQuery и плагины к нему не судьба?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создаете форму с enctype="multipart/form-data" для фото и другую форму для текстовых данных

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">            
<input id="image" accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif" name="image" type="file">                     
</form>

<form action="" method="post">                      
<input id="text" name="text" type="text">
<input type="submit" value="ГОТОВО">            
</form>
```

И затем уже при помощи jQuery при отправке одной формы Ajax'ом, автоматически посылать и вторую Ajax'ом

Comment: Зачем две формы? Можно обойтись и одной!!!

Answer (score 0):

ну, как вариант, можно формировать запрос с картинкой на роут вида uploader/?text=[YOUR TEXT], и принимать соответственно файл и GET параметр text вместе.